# Эффект перебора символов

Tags: c++, строки, анимация

Долго пытался сделать, генерировать то я могу рандомный стринг но делать повтор чтобы совпадало не выходит, вопрос как сделать это как на гифке ниже?

[image: Вот что нужно сделать]

Comment: я что-то не понял: вы генерируете рандомный стринг, при этом хочете, чтобы это строка повторяла предыдущую?

Comment: Просто сохраняйте результат, либо же выводите нужную строку. По сути же можно просто несколько секунд генерить что угодно, а по истечении времени показывать любую нужную строку...

Comment: Это пример, на самом деле мне нужно чтобы каждая буква подбиралась таким себе брутом (если буква подобралась, то делаем continue)

Comment: Ничего не ясно. Что за "повтор чтобы совпадало "? Что совпадало? С чем совпадало?

Comment: У меня есть слово например EXAMPLE
Я хочу чтобы это слово по буквам подбиралось из рандомного стринга

Comment: Объясняйте, что значит "слово по буквам подбиралось из рандомного стринга ". В вашей анимированной гифке никакого подбора по буквам в упор не видно.

Comment: генерируете N символов слова рандомно до тех пор, пока слово не совпадёт с искомым. Можно по очереди - сначала генерировать первый символ до тех пор пока он не совпадёт с первым символом искомого слова, потом второй и так далее

Comment: Я имел в виду подбор каждой буквы по очереди, тобишь сгенерировался стринг например Abcdxz*/, после чего по очереди идет подбор букв (если первая буква стринга совпала с E, вторая с X и так пока не совпадет все слово)

Comment: Вам не нужно на самом деле подбирать символы рандомом) Вполне достаточно "крутить" любые символы (кроме "искомого") необходимое число итераций, а потом-таки устанавливать требуемый.

Comment: я понимаю чего он хочет добиться, как в фильмах показывают, типа взлом - проходят от 0-9 и когда-то типа находят правильную цифру. так же и тут, вы идете по азбуке и тд.. и по истечению рандомного времени и попадание на нужную букву, показываете ее

Comment: Похоже, это просто реклама суицида.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так, "открывая" по буквам:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void sleep(long ms) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(ms));
}

char getRandomSymbol(char from, char to) {
    if (from > to) {
        char temp = from;
        from = to;
        to = temp;
    }
    else if (from == to) return from;

    return from + rand() % ((to + 1) - from);
}

void rotateSymbol(char target, int rotationDelay) {
    char randTry;
    do {
        randTry = getRandomSymbol('A', 'Z');
    } while (randTry == target);

    cout << randTry;
    sleep(rotationDelay);
    cout << '\b';
}

void rotateString(const char* word, int iterationsNumber, int rotationDelay) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); ++i) {
        char symbol = word[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < iterationsNumber; ++j) {
            rotateSymbol(symbol, rotationDelay);
        }
        cout << symbol;
    }
}

int main(int argn, char **argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));  

    const int ROTATE_TIMES = 5;
    const int ROTATION_DELAY = 100;

    if (argn > 1) {
        rotateString(argv[1], ROTATE_TIMES, ROTATION_DELAY);
    } else {
        rotateString("Hello World!", ROTATE_TIMES, ROTATION_DELAY);
    }

    cout << endl << "Press [ENTER] key...";
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: А можно как-то symbol и randTry превратить в const char* ? 
Для меня это важно

Comment: @GreorgheLanescu, `symbol` - можно, ведь там рассматривается исходная строка, а `randTry` - нет смысла, ибо там речь именно про некоторое новое значение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тогда нечего не будет если я переведу symbol и randTry в стринг?

Comment: @GreorgheLanescu,это же отдельные символы, зачем тут стринг?

Comment: Просто там где мне нужно использовать этот код у меня 2 варианта, либо использовать это как const char* либо переводить в стринг и выводить. (Я говорю о том что я не смогу вывести char)

Comment: @GreorgheLanescu, перепишите код так, чтобы вывод был не на консоль, а в некий буфер, а его уже там передавайте куда вам надо на каждом шаге.

Comment: я просто заменил cout << ... на свою функцию отрисовки (я через нее все отрисовываю) - Text(int x, int y, bool center, bool shadow, Color color, const char* format, ...); 
И в итоге вышло вот такое - Render->Text(6, 6, false, true, Color::Green(), to_string(symbol).c_str());
Но по какой-то причине данный код просто крашит мою программу...

Comment: @GreorgheLanescu, наверняка ваша цель не поддерживает `cout << 'b'`, поэтомуо туда нужно передавать не отдельный символ, а все то, что видно на экране в данный момент.

Comment: И, да, перегрузки `std::to_string(char)` [не существует](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), у вас срабатывает скорее всего `std::to_string(int)`, а это совсем не то, что нужно. Чисто теоретически, можно было бы использовать конструктор `std::string(const char*, size_t)` (вида `std::string(&word[i], 1)`), но, как я уже писал, в логику вашей программы это не вписывается совершенно.